# SQLite3 query fails, the error does not

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

SQLite3 query fails, the error does not. 
  Insert data in the database ok, but does not get the data, what is my fault?

```
 protected function db2Array($data){
    $arr = array();
    while ($row = $data -> fetchArray(\SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
            $arr[] = $row;
            }
    return $arr;
    }

function getNews() {
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT msgs.id as id, title, category.name as category, description, source, datetime
          FROM msgs, category
          WHERE category.id = msgs.category
          ORDER BY msgs.id DESC";
        $res = $this->_db -> query($sql);
        if(!is_object($res)){
        throw new Exception ($this->_db -> LastErrorMsg());
        return $this->db2Array($res);
        }
    } catch (Exception $exs){
        //$exs -> getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indenting the code a bit makes it a bit more clear;

```php
if(!is_object($res)){
    throw new Exception ($this->_db -> LastErrorMsg());
    return $this->db2Array($res);  // This will never execute due to the throw
}
```

If there's an error, you throw an exception and then (in code that won't execute) return the result. If there is no error, you don't return anything.

You need to move the return outside the `if` scope;

```
if(!is_object($res)) {
    throw new Exception ($this->_db -> LastErrorMsg());
}
return $this->db2Array($res);
```

Now the code will throw an exception on error, and return a result otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Now my exception is ok, but my query is: array (size=0)
  empty. Where it is still a mistake??

Comment: At my query was a mistake, now works correctly, thanks!

Comment: Your answer helped. How my question closed or marked answered?

Comment: @naut92 To the left of my answer there is a shadow of a check mark. Click that to mark the question as answered.